# Login to multiple servers using one of the two passwords used for authentication using Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python.
I am using Paramiko module to login to the Linux servers. However I have 2 different passwords for authentication and I want the server to be logged in using either of them. In case both fails, I am raising the exception for it.
I am facing problem when I have to use the second password. Here is sample for the same.
server.txt is having the list of servers

```
file1 = 'D:\Linux\server.txt'
with open(file1) as f:
    switch_ip = f.readlines()
switch_ip = [x.strip() for x in switch_ip]

username = "user1"

password1 = "abcd2"
password2 = "efcdrf2"

def simple_out(cmd):
    try:
            ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            x=[]

            ssh.connect(IP,port =22,username = username, password = password1 or password2)
            pass
            time.sleep(2)
            stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
            line1 = stdout.readline()               #read line by line
            while line1:
                split_words = line1.split()         #List
                #      split_words.insert(0,IP)
                print split_words       
                str1 = ' '.join(split_words)        #String
                x.append(str1)
                line1=stdout.readline()
            return [x]
    except (paramiko.BadHostKeyException, paramiko.AuthenticationException, paramiko.SSHException, socket.error) as e:
        time.sleep(2)
        buf = StringIO.StringIO(e)
        line3 = buf.read()
        y=[line3]
        return [y]

for IP in switch_ip:
        output = simple_out("df -h")                                            # will call function and execute command
        out1 = output[0]                                                                #t     
        for items in out1:
            book = xlrd.open_workbook('D:\\Linux\\xlwt example.xls')
            sheet2 = book.sheet_by_index(0)
            row_count = sheet2.nrows
            column_count = 1
            sheet1.write(row_count, 0, IP)
            sheet1.write(row_count, column_count, items)
            wb.save('D:\\Linux\\xlwt example.xls')

time.sleep(2)
```

I want to login to the servers using either of the 2 passwords

Comment: and what exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: ``ssh.connect(IP,port =22,username = username, password = password1 or password2)`` . isn't valid code.  I would guess that this is the problem

Comment: It is going into exception part without trying the second password and printing Authentication failed.

Comment: Yes @Vorsprung, this is not working, any other way to solve this.. I tried using if statement as well to use the different passwords. Still it goes to except part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use try catch block for each password and continue in your program see below example:

```
try:
  ssh.connect(IP,port =22,username = username, password = password1)
except paramiko.AuthenticationException as e: #catch other exceptions as well
  ssh.connect(IP,port =22,username = username, password = password2)
```